# Warning, when I run a PHP script

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

When I run a php script in console, I'm getting a following warning:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/php_mcrypt.dll' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/php_mcrypt.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/php_curl.dll' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/php_curl.dll: invalid ELF header in Unknown on line 0

The PHP script is correct, because it works on other comuputers.

I have an Ubuntu and server apache2

Comment: A DLL on Linux? Aren't DLLs a Windows concept?

Comment: Does it work when you run the script through the Apache server?

Comment: Did you by any chance copy over a php.ini file from an existing Windows installation?  Because as Prahalad already said, there are no dll's on Linux, php extensions use the .so extension

Comment: If you use xampp for development and just copy over your htdocs files you shouldn't have issues.  I do this between Linux and Win 7 through a repository.

Comment: The second line seems to suggest there are actually .dll files present on the system.  Did you copy them there?  If not, I think you need to have a chat with whoever butchered that system together...

Comment: You can tell PHP to stop loading those extensions 

`$ grep -Hrv ";" /etc/php5 | grep -i "extension="`

Comment: It would seem you've uncommented lines in php.ini for some extensions without altering the file name. php_mcrypt.dll should for example probably be php_mcrypt.so.

Answer (score 1):

Check your php.ini currently you are trying to load a windows extension on a linux server.

Have a look in the folder /etc/php5/apache2/ for any file with a name like mcrypt and see if it references a dll file. If so, delete that file and restart apache

If you have ubuntu then `sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt` will enable mcrypt for you

Comment: I found a solution to the problem! In php.ini i had an uncommented following lines:

    extension=php_mcrypt.dll
    extension=php_curl.dll

thanks for help!